# Gnome Shell Title Bar won't change

Tags: gnome, themes

I've Gnome Shell 3.8.4 on Ubuntu 13.10 and `gnome-tweak-tool` but I can't change the title bar (I think that it's metacity-1 that does it) with any theme. I can change icons, everything else on the window and the shell theme.
Any ideia? I've tried many theme's from gnome-look.org and I've verified if it has the metacity-1 folder.

Comment: I confirm this bug

Comment: I had the same problem of some themes not changing but some does, I had to move themes from `~/.themes` to `/usr/share/themes` now I am able to change title bar

Comment: @borislemke -  The bug is resolved by adding [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/), which add this option to dconf:`org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name`, so the gnome-shell themes can be used.

Answer (score 2):

There is workaround for this.
Open **dconf** editor and change setting named:

```
org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences.theme
```

to your theme (**Adwaita** or just enter **Default**)

Comment: You can always provide a helpful link: [`https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/dconf-editor/`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/dconf-editor/). After installing [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/) extension, you can then use `org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name NAME_OF_THEME`

Comment: On terminal: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Adwaita`, `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme Adwaita`but anyway is necessary to enable the User theme extension.

Answer (score 2):

To get a user specified shell theme, use this extension:
[User Themes - GNOME Shell Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/).

Install it from the extension, page and make sure it is on in [`gnome-tweak-tool`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/gnome-tweak-tool/):
[image]

and here are the results - with it off, and with it on:
[image]

You can then use [`gnome-tweak-tool`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/gnome-tweak-tool/) to set the theme:

[image]

By the way, I recommend the [Zukiwi Theme](http://lassekongo83.deviantart.com/art/Zukiwi-313347909) - you may be able to install that with:

```
sudo apt-get install zukiwi
```